# Is there a reader and writer principle for the (posix) message queue?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

Is there a reader and writer principle for the (posix) message queue? 
I want to send integers from thread A (writer) to thread B (reader).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "principle".  It is certainly possible to put an integer into a message, send that message to a mq, and let another thread or process dequeue the message and extract the integer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes thats what i mean. Like for example the posix pipe you have pipe(); read(); write(); But i want something similar for posix message queue

Comment: It's still a bit unclear to me what you're asking, but it seems that either it is much too broad for SO, or it belies a disappointing lack research.  The Linux manual contains [a message queue overview](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) that I think covers POSIX message queues pretty well.  That is, it presents the general usage model and enumerates the standard mq functions; these aspects are not Linux-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sending from one thread and receiving in another is safe.  Similar to using pipes or sockets etc.